# Guitar Hero 5 - how to play career?

Tags: guitar-hero-5

I'm new to this game, and when I practice, I select a normal game. However, on career and quick play, I get something odd.

There are no boxes to hit, and there are rainbow lines. I can press how ever many buttons I want, and hit the guitar non-stop, to receive a 3 star level completion. Why does it work like that?

Comment: Have you tried another song? I haven't played Guitar Hero in the while, but this sounds like the finales/drum rolls from Rock Band, that are at certain parts of the song for bonus points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you're on beginner mode. Try increasing the difficulty level.

Comment: Yes. Beginner mode removes the pitch aspect of the game, only expecting the player to get the rhythm correct.